# Tkinter: Can't add more than 3 PhotoImages to a list for animation?

Tags: python, animation, tkinter

I'm trying to program a game in Tkinter (trust that I'd much rather use another better-suited library), and I'm having trouble coding in animations. I tried 2 ways of working around the problem but both have failed.

What I've done is to write an Animation class, which, in my first implementation, takes a list of PhotoImages, and deletes/draws each frame:

```
class Animation():
    def __init__(self, container, pos, images, framerate):
        self.container = container
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.images = copy(images)
        self.imagescopy = copy(images)
        self.framerate = framerate # ms between frames
        self.done = False

    def animate(self):
        if len(self.images)>0:
            self.container.delete("currentframe") 
            self.container.create_image(self.x, self.y, image = self.images.pop(0), tag = "currentframe")
            self.animation = self.container.after(self.framerate, self.animate)
        else:
            self.container.delete("currentframe")
            self.container.after_cancel(self.animation)
            self.done = True
```

In the init method of the class which draws the Tk window, I loaded the PhotoImages (I tried this with a simple placeholder 5 frame animation):

```
for i in range(1,6):
            self.imgs_playbgready.append(PhotoImage(file ='Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready'+str(i)+'.gif'))
```

But when I try to execute the program, it takes very very long to load beyond the third image. Even writing out each line explicitly like so:

```
self.imgs_playbgready = [PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready1.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready2.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready3.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready4.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready5.gif') ]
```

didn't help. Removing the last 2 items seems to make everything fine, so it looks like there's a limit on 3 PhotoImages in a list though I can't imagine why that'd be the case?

In my second implementation, I tried to change the `animate` method so that the PhotoImages would be 'lazily loaded' (so now self.images is a list of file names rather than PhotoImages):

```
def animate(self):
            if len(self.images)>0:
                self.container.delete("currentframe") 
                image = PhotoImage(file = self.images.pop(0))
                self.container.create_image(self.x, self.y, image = image, tag = "currentframe")
                self.animation = self.container.after(self.framerate, self.animate)
            else:
                self.container.delete("currentframe")
                self.container.after_cancel(self.animation)
                self.done = True
```

Now when I try to run the program it freezes at frame 4 and I have to force quit. Again, it seems 3 is the magic number?

I'm not really sure at all what's going on with this. From googling about animation in Tkinter, redrawing PhotoImages frame by frame seems the way to go. Please be patient with me because I only started learning to use the Tkinter library last week. Any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Thanks for your help.
To clarify the points raised in the comment (full working code at the end):

It takes a few minutes before the last two images load in and the program starts up. My framerate as defined in the `Animation class` is more like an inverse framerate (number of miliseconds between each redraw) as you can see in the `animate` function. My whole code is really quite long so I will try to extract the more relevant parts (for the first implementation I tried). Basically in my GUI class (named `PlayArea`), under the `__init__` method, I try to load in the image list for the animation as well as create an `Animation` instance:

```
class PlayArea():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()

      .....

        #---------------------
        # Button and background images
        #---------------------

      ......

        self.imgs_playbgready = [PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready1.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready2.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready3.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready4.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready5.gif') ]

        .......
        self.ani_playbgready = Animation(self.playCanvas,(self.playWidth/2, self.playHeight/2),self.imgs_playbgready, 5000)
```

The animation will only run after a user clicks a button, and the command callback for the button is this(I've put in only the relevant portions):

```
startGame(self):

        # Play Area
        self.playCanvas.delete("bgready")
        self.ani_playbgready.animate() # animating the images
```

I know for sure that the program is freezing up after loading the third PhotoImage, because when I try to do the loading using a `for` loop, and print the list after each loop, I can see it hang up in the fourth one. As mentioned, this code works as long as I only load 3 images into the list.  In other words, it probably isn't a problem with my `animate` method

The monstrous block of working code as requested:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from copy import deepcopy, copy

#------------------------------------------------
#       Player, Controller, Levels, and Customer
#------------------------------------------------
class Player():
    '''
    Player class to keep track of progress of specific player.
    Progress and highscore will be written to a save file
    '''
    def __init__(self, name = "Default", highscore = 0, currentlevel = 1):
        self.name = name
        self.highscore = highscore
        self.currentlevel = currentlevel


class Controller():
    '''
    Controller which keeps track of score as well as the timer.

    To be instantiated by the GUI class to determine the score and time left to display
    '''

    def __init__(self):
        self.score = 0
        self.level = 1
        self.timer = 10


    def runTimer(self):
        if self.timer > 0:
            self.timer -= 1
        else:
            self.timer = 10

class Levels():
    '''
    Contains the commands(tasks) for each level, as well as the order of customers and the
    corresponding answers.

    To be instantiated by the GUI class to determine the current command and customer to display
    '''
    def __init__(self):

        #--------------------------------------------------------------
        # Initialize commands, anwers and customers for each level (hardcode for now, may be a way to
        # randomize or dynamically generate challenges depending on the level design)
        # Customers can have more than one attribute, so we store it as a tuple
        # Answers for each customer can be more than one pizza (eg. for a while loop), so store it as a tuple
        # If the statement doesn't execute, correct answer is to move on to the next customer
        #---------------------------------------------------------------

        # Level 1

        # Action images
        self.img_pepperoni = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\pepperoniup.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\pepperonihover.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\pepperonidown.gif'))
        self.img_hawaiian = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\hawaiianup.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\hawaiianhover.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\hawaiiandown.gif'))
        self.img_vegetarian = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\vegetarianup.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\vegetarianhover.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\vegetariandown.gif'))
        self.img_nextcustomer = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\nextcustomerup.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\nextcustomerhover.gif'),
                              PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Actions\\nextcustomerdown.gif'))

        level1commands = ['if customer_is_red:\n\tserve pepperoni', 'if customer_is_blue:\n\tserve hawaiian']
        level1customers = [('red'), ('green')] #make this a dict corresponding to image too?
        level1answers = [('pepperoni'), ('next')]
        level1actions = {'pepperoni': self.img_pepperoni , 'hawaiian':self.img_hawaiian, 'vegetarian': self.img_vegetarian,
                        'next': self.img_nextcustomer}


        self.levelscommands = [level1commands]
        self.levelscustomers = [level1customers]
        self.levelsanswers = [level1answers]
        self.levelsactions = [level1actions]



class Customer():
    def __init__(self, **attributes):
        for k,v in attributes:
            self.k = v

#--------------------------------
#       Animations
#--------------------------------

class Animation():
    def __init__(self, container, pos, images, framerate):
        self.container = container
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.images = copy(images)
        self.imagescopy = copy(images)
        self.framerate = framerate # ms between frames
        self.done = False

    def animate(self):
        if len(self.images)>0:
            print "animating", len(self.images), self.images
            self.container.delete("currentframe") # won't throw an error if non-existant
            print self.images[0], "image name"
            image = PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready1.gif')
            print image, "image"
            self.container.create_image(self.x, self.y, image = image, tag = "currentframe")
            self.animation = self.container.after(self.framerate, self.animate)
        else:
            print "finished"
            self.container.delete("currentframe")
            self.container.after_cancel(self.animation)
            self.done = True

    def resetAnimation(self):
        self.done = False
        self.images = copy(self.imagescopy)

#-------------------------
#       GUI classes
#-------------------------

class PlayArea():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Pizza Program!")

        #------------------------------------------------------------
        # Initialize player, controller, levels and customer classes
        #------------------------------------------------------------
        self.player = Player()
        self.controller = Controller()
        self.levels = Levels()
        self.customer = Customer()

        #---------------------
        # Button and background images
        #---------------------
        self.img_buttonstart = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_startup.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_starthover.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_startdown.gif'))
        self.img_buttonpause = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_pauseup.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_pausehover.gif'),
                                PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_pausedown.gif'))
        self.img_buttonresume = (PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_resumeup.gif'),
                                 PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_resumehover.gif'),
                                 PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\Controller\\button_resumedown.gif'))

        self.img_playbgplay = Image.open("Graphics\\PlayArea\\bgplay.gif")
        self.img_playbgready = Image.open("Graphics\\PlayArea\\bgready.gif")


    #    self.imgs_playbgready = [PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready1.gif'),
    #                            PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready2.gif'),
    #                            PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready3.gif'),
    #                            PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready4.gif'),
    #                            PhotoImage(file = 'Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready5.gif') ]

        #-----------------------
        #   Animations
        #-----------------------
        self.imgs_playbgready = []
        self.imgs_startserving = []

        for i in range(1,4):# change later
            self.imgs_playbgready.append('Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_bgready'+str(i)+'.gif')
            self.imgs_startserving.append('Graphics\\PlayArea\\ani_startserving'+str(i)+'.gif')

        #self.imgs_playbgready = []
        #for filename in imgs_playbgready:
        #    self.imgs_playbgready.append(PhotoImage(file = filename))
        #--------------
        # Font styles
        #--------------
        self.controlFont = tkFont.Font(family = "Calibri", size = 10, weight = "bold" )
        self.commandFont = tkFont.Font(family = "Courier New", size = 14, weight = "bold")


        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        # Frames to contain the play area (graphics), the command area (what players must do),
        # the controller area (start button, timer, score), and action area (possible actions players can take)
        #-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        self.playFrame = Frame(self.window, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0)
        self.commandFrame = Frame(self.window, bd =0, highlightthickness =0)
        self.controlFrame = Frame(self.window, bd =0, highlightthickness =0)
        self.actionsFrame = Frame(self.window, bd =0, highlightthickness =0)

        self.commandFrame.grid(column = 1, row = 1)
        self.playFrame.grid(column = 1, row = 2)
        self.controlFrame.grid(column = 2, row = 1)
        self.actionsFrame.grid(column = 2, row = 2)

        self.actionsFrame.pack_propagate(False)
        #self.actionsFrame.columnconfigure(1,weight=1)
        #self.window.columnconfigure(2, weight =1)

        #-----------------------------------
        # Play Area Elements
        #-----------------------------------
        self.playWidth = 500
        self.playHeight = 500
        self.playCanvas = Canvas(self.playFrame, width = self.playWidth, height = self.playHeight, bd = -2)
        self.playCanvas.pack()

        resized = self.img_playbgplay.resize((self.playWidth, self.playHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.img_playbgplay = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)
        resized = self.img_playbgready.resize((self.playWidth, self.playHeight), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        self.img_playbgready = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized)

        self.playCanvas.create_image(self.playWidth/2, self.playHeight/2, image = self.img_playbgplay)
        self.playCanvas.create_image(self.playWidth/2, self.playHeight/2, image = self.img_playbgready,tag = "bgready")

        # Bgready animation for when start is pressed
        self.ani_playbgready = Animation(self.playCanvas,(self.playWidth/2, self.playHeight/2),self.imgs_playbgready, 5000)
        self.ani_startserving = Animation(self.playCanvas,(self.playWidth/2, self.playHeight/2), self.imgs_playbgready,5000)

        # Controller elements
        # timer and score labels only appear after game starts
        self.controlColor = "sky blue"
        self.controlWidth = 200
        self.controlHeight = 200
        self.controllerCanvas = Canvas(self.controlFrame, width = self.controlWidth, height = self.controlHeight, bg = self.controlColor,
                                        bd =0 , highlightthickness =0)
        # Frame for containing button, timer and score
        self.controlLabelFrame = LabelFrame(self.controllerCanvas, bd = 0, highlightthickness = 0, relief = "ridge", bg = self.controlColor)
        #print self.controlLabelFrame.config(), "configs for controlLabelFrame"


        self.btStart = Button(self.controlLabelFrame, command = self.startGame, highlightthickness =0, bd =0,
                            bg = self.controlColor, image = self.img_buttonstart[0])
        self.btPause = Button(self.controlLabelFrame, command = self.pauseGame, highlightthickness =0, bd =0,
                            bg = self.controlColor, image = self.img_buttonpause[0])
        self.btResume = Button(self.controlLabelFrame, command = self.resumeGame, highlightthickness =0, bd =0,
                            bg = self.controlColor, image = self.img_buttonstart[0])

        self.controllerCanvas.pack()
        self.btStart.grid(row=1, pady = 5)
        self.controllerCanvas.create_window(self.controlWidth/2, self.controlHeight/2, window = self.controlLabelFrame)
        #Toggle button image
        self.changeButtonImage(self.btStart, self.img_buttonstart)

        # Timer label
        self.timerText = StringVar()
        self.timerLabel = Label(self.controlLabelFrame, textvariable = self.timerText, bg = self.controlColor, font = self.controlFont)
        self.timerLabel.grid( row = 2, pady=5)

        # Level label
        self.levelText = StringVar()
        self.levelLabel = Label(self.controlLabelFrame, textvariable = self.levelText, bg = self.controlColor, font = self.controlFont)
        self.levelLabel.grid( row = 3, pady=5)


        # Command elements
        self.commandColor = "light sky blue"
        self.commandWidth = 500
        self.commandHeight = 200
        self.commandCanvas = Canvas(self.commandFrame, width = self.commandWidth, height = self.commandHeight, bg = self.commandColor)
        self.commandCanvas.pack()
        self.commText = StringVar()
        self.commLabel = Label(self.commandCanvas, textvariable = self.commText, bg = self.commandColor, font = self.commandFont)
        self.commandCanvas.create_window(self.commandWidth/2, self.commandHeight/2, window = self.commLabel)

        # Action elements
        self.actionColor = "cornflower blue"
        self.actionWidth = 200
        self.actionHeight = 500
        self.actionsFrame.config(width = self.actionWidth, height = self.actionHeight, bg = self.actionColor,)
        #self.actionCanvas = Canvas(self.actionsFrame, width = self.actionWidth, height = self.actionHeight, bg = self.actionColor, highlightthickness =0)
        #self.actionCanvas.pack()




        self.window.mainloop()

    #-------------------------------------
    #       Step methods
    #       (for checking conditions each step)
    #-------------------------------------
    def checkAnimation(self, animation, triggerevent, *args):
        if not animation.done:
            self.window.after(100, self.checkAnimation)
        else:
            triggerevent(args)
    #-------------------------------------
    #       Controller methods
    #-------------------------------------

    def changeButtonImage(self, button, images):

        def toImage(event, button, image):
            button["image"] = image

        up, hover, down = images

        button.bind("<Enter>", lambda event, button = button, image = hover : toImage(event, button, image))
        button.bind("<Leave>", lambda event, button = button, image = up : toImage(event, button, image))
        button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, button = button, image = down : toImage(event, button, image))
        button.bind("<ButtonRelease-1>", lambda event, button = button, image = up : toImage(event, button, image))


    def updateController(self):
        self.timerText.set("Next Customer: " + str(self.controller.timer))
        self.controller.runTimer()
        self.update = self.controlFrame.after(1000, self.updateController)

    def startGame(self):

        #--------------------------
        # Update controller elements
        #-----------------------------

        # Change button
        self.btStart.grid_remove()
        self.btPause.grid(row=1, pady = 5)
        self.changeButtonImage(self.btPause, self.img_buttonpause)

        # Timer label
        self.timerText.set("Next Customer:" + str(self.controller.timer))

        # Level label
        self.levelText.set("Level: " + str(self.controller.level))

        self.updateController()

        #--------------------------------
        # Access level commands, customers, answers, and set command display
        #--------------------------------

        # Commands
        self.levelcommands = deepcopy(self.levels.levelscommands[self.controller.level-1]) #copy the list
        self.currentcommand = self.levelcommands.pop(0)
        self.displayCommand(self.currentcommand)

        # Actions
        self.levelactions = copy(self.levels.levelsactions[self.controller.level-1])
        self.btActions = []
        for action, img in self.levelactions.iteritems():
            if action != "next":
                self.btActions.append(Button(self.actionsFrame, command = self.servePizza,
                                        highlightthickness =0, bd =0, bg = self.actionColor, image = img[0]))
            else:
                self.btActions.append(Button(self.actionsFrame, command = self.nextCustomer,
                                        highlightthickness =0, bd =0, bg = self.actionColor, image= img[0]))

            index = self.btActions.index(self.btActions[-1]) +1
            self.btActions[-1].pack(pady = 35)
            self.changeButtonImage(self.btActions[-1], img)


        # Play Area
        self.playCanvas.delete("bgready")
        self.ani_playbgready.animate()
        #self.checkAnimation(self.ani_playbgready, self.ani_startserving.animate)
        self.levelcustomers = deepcopy(self.levels.levelscustomers[self.controller.level-1]) #copy the list
        self.currentcustomer = self.levelcustomers.pop(0)
        #self.displayCustomer(self.currentcustomer) #need to write this method

        # Answers
        self.levelanswers = self.levels.levelsanswers[self.controller.level-1][:] # no nested elements
        self.currentanswer = self.levelanswers.pop(0)

    def pauseGame(self):
        #Pause controller updating

        # Change button
        self.btPause.grid_remove()
        self.btResume.grid(row=1, pady = 5)
        self.changeButtonImage(self.btResume, self.img_buttonresume)

        self.controlFrame.after_cancel(self.update)

    def resumeGame(self):
        # Resume controller updating
        # Change button
        self.btResume.grid_remove()
        self.btPause.grid(row=1, pady = 5)
        self.changeButtonImage(self.btResume, self.img_buttonpause)

        self.updateController()

    def readyLevel(self):
        pass
    #---------------------------------
    #       Command methods
    #---------------------------------

    def updateCommand(self):
        pass

    def displayCommand(self, command):
        self.commText.set(command)

    #--------------------------------
    #       Action methods
    #--------------------------------

    def servePizza(self):
        pass

    def nextCustomer(self):
        pass


PlayArea()
```

Comment: There is no limit of 3 images in a list or in tkinter. What is the framerate, and how big are your images? When you say it takes a long time, is that measured in hours? Minutes? Seconds? 100ths of seconds? There must be more to the problem than what you're showing. Can you include a complete working program?

Comment: I don't know what's causing this particular problem, but I'd highly recommend a bit of refactoring to allow for saving a reference to the drawn image and then reconfiguring your `Canvas` with `self.container.itemconfig(saved_img_ref, self.images[i])` instead of deleting/redrawing things.